# How can I import JSON from a text file into MongoDB with ObjectID's?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, bson

I want to import data into MongoDB, including reference ID's to set up our tests. I'm using the `node-mongo-seeds` module.

Some of our data has reference dependencies and I'm stuck in a chicken and egg situation where some of the data needs to have a reference ID in order for things to work.

I've exported the data I need and converted it all to Extended JSON, e.g. 
each `ObjectID("<id>")` becomes `{ "$oid", "<id>" }`

I have tried out the `mongodb-extended-json` package.

I wish to do something like:

`db.collection(collection_name).insert(EJSON.parse(contents), /* callback */)`

However its coming back with the error 

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

Which seems to be same error as if the contents had the text BSON representation `ObjectId"<id>"`.

Is there a way to insert data into Mongo in this way?

I've created a fork if anyone wants to have a look with just a minor change: https://github.com/adamski/node-mongo-seeds/commit/266e4aac32032beb75782ece03e163504223e522

Comment: Where are you exporting the data from? MongoDB? Could you export using mongodump, preserving the type information in BSON?

Comment: The data is coming from Robomongo. In other cases, for flat documents, I am just removing the ObjectIds. I will try mongodump.